# In infinite-dimensional space, does linear mapping always have a fixed point?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

In infinite-dimensional space, does linear mapping that satisfy the strictly nonexpansive always have a fixed point?
I believe the answer is no and we can construct a counterexample to show that such as in $X=c_0$  or $X=l^\infty$ but I am still working on constructing my example.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by a linear mapping having "a fixed point".  Zero is always a fixed point of a linear mapping, regardless of the "strictly nonexpansive" property.  Also, it is unclear what you expect to obtain about an infinite-dimensional space that cannot already be said for a finite-dimensional space.  Perhaps some information about "constructing my example" would clear it up for me?

Comment: Maybe you mean something different by fixed point, but whenever $T:V\to V $ is a linear mapping, $T(0)=0$.

Comment: So a linear mapping always have a fixed point if dim(E)< $\infty$ or dim(E)=$\infty$ ?

Zero is always a fixed point but if the sequence converges to two different points like then the limit is not unique and we do not have a fixed point.

Comment: Trivially zero is a fixed point of any linear mapping, even an unbounded one.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. So I need to prove that:
 if E is a complete space and dim(E)=$ \infty$ and $T:E \to E$ is a linear mapping satisfying $||T(a)−T(y)||<||a−b||$ then T is always have a fixed point. 
 Instead of constructing a counterexample showing that T not always have a fixed point.

Comment: I have a nagging suspicion that I missed the point of this exercise in constructing an infinite dimensional counterexample.  You mention a sequence in comments but not in the body of the Question.  A legitimate problem is to ask whether, given any initial point $x_0$ the sequence generated by repeatedly applying a linear map $T$ must converge or have a convergent subsequence.  Your Question does not ask that because it asks about fixed points of $T $ but does not define any sequence of points.

Comment: My question is similar to this

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653615/show-that-tx-ty-lt-x-y-when-x-neq-y-but-the-mapping-has-no-fixed?rq=1
 
That question is nonlinear with finite dimensional. But I am considering a linear mapping with infinite dimensional space that has no fixed point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, there is no linear mapping that is without a fixed point since trivially the zero vector will always satisfy $T(0) = 0$ for any linear mapping $T:V\to V$.  It may be that a linear map has only this one fixed point, e.g. the zero map that sends every $x\in V$ to zero necessarily has but that one fixed point.  Indeed any strictly contractive linear map, $||T(x-y)|| \lt ||x-y||$ when $x\neq y$, has no fixed point other than $T(0)=0$.

However an interesting question is whether there can be a choice of initial point $x_0$ such that the sequence defined by $x_{n+1} = T(x_n)$ has no convergent subsequence under the restriction that $||T(x-y)|| \le ||x-y||$.

A standard example of this is the shift operator on $\ell^\infty$.  That is, define $T(x)$ to be the result of shifting all the entries of $x$ to the right (and introducing a new zero entry to fill the first component).  For any choice of nonzero $x$, the sequence $T^n(x)$ will neither converge nor have any convergent subsequence using the $\infty$-norm.

The shift operator on $\ell^\infty$ satisfies $||T(x-y)|| = ||x-y||$.

Comment: Clear, now I know what I need to do. I appreciate your help.